# Clipping polygon layer to another polygon layer based on matching attributes using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip, split-by-attribute

Working in QGIS, I have two polygon layers:

- Building Footprint Polygon Layer
- Parcel Polygon Layer

These two layers have a matching field in the attributes known as "Parcel Number". I would like to clip the building footprint features to be within the parcel polygon features based on matching parcel numbers. So if I have a building footprint feature that overlaps two parcel polygons, I would like to clip the building footprint to be within the parcel polygon that has the same parcel number as the building footprint.

Answer (score 3):

**QGIS3.0+**

Let us assume we have a `buildings` layer (orange polygons: A, B, C) which is linked to another layer `parcel` (gray polygons: 101, 102, 103) by `Parcel_Num` attribute field.

[image]

We can use **Geometry by Expression** tool in `Processing Toolbox | Vector geometry`.

Click on the large Epsilon mark to open an `expression dialog` window:

[image]

Expression is:

```
intersection($geometry, geometry(get_feature('parcel', 'Parcel_Num', "Parcel_Num")))
```

And we will get red dashed polygons shown in a picture below, in which we can visually confirm *A - 102, B - 101, C - 103* pairs.

[image]